# Plesk Obsidian (18.0.48) - 413 Request Entity Too Large (nginx)

Tags: php, apache, nginx, plesk

Hello recently I set up a server using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Plesk Obsidian 18.0.48. However I encountered a problem when uploading files around 1GB of size.
The website I am running is a docker-compose project with Python 3.10 as codebase.

I know that this question has been asked already, but for some reason nothing seems to work for me.

**What I already tried**

- I created a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/aa_client_max_body.conf` with the content `client_max_body_size 2048m;`
- I also tried adding `client_max_body_size 2048m;` to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf => http` (I commented out the content of the other file to prevent misconfiguration errors)
- I created the file `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/panel.ini` with the following content

```
[webserver]
nginxClientMaxBodySize =
```

- I added `client_max_body_size 0;` to `Domain => my.domain => Hosting & DNS => Apache & nginx Settings => Additional nginx directives`
- I added `LimitRequestBody 0` to `Domain => my.domain => Hosting & DNS => Apache & nginx Settings => Additional directives for HTTP` and `Additional directives for HTTPS`
- I increased the values of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` under `Domain => my.domain => PHP Settings` both to `2048M`

The website is a https subdomain.

Thanks for every help :)